# How can one read from multiple models in a single loop in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

How can one read from multiple models in a single loop in a view. If I had already combined this model

```
 public class ViewModel
 {
   public IEnumerable<Student> Student{ get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Course> Course{ get; set; }
 }
```

What I need to achieve in view is this

```
 @model Admin.Models.ViewModel

 @foreach (var item in Model)
     {

         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName) //from Student model           
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course1) //from Course model
      }
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861918/return-a-viewmodel-with-ienumerables-to-view-and-use-razor-to-loop-variables-in. You need to follow the same solution, which is creating a view model which has both the properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this Model like this

```
@model Admin.Models.ViewModel

 @foreach (var item in Model.Student)
     {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName) //from Student model           
     }

 @foreach (var item in Model.Course)
     {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course1) //from Course model
     }
```